# Encountered a duplicated sql alias [company_id] during auto-discovery of a native-sql query

Tags: java, database, hibernate

Here is my problem :

> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path
> [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Encountered a
> duplicated sql alias [company_id] during auto-discovery of a
> native-sql query; nested exception is
> org.hibernate.loader.custom.NonUniqueDiscoveredSqlAliasException:
> Encountered a duplicated sql alias [company_id] during auto-discovery
> of a native-sql query] with root cause
>
> org.hibernate.loader.custom.NonUniqueDiscoveredSqlAliasException:
> Encountered a duplicated sql alias [company_id] during auto-discovery
> of a native-sql query

My 3 entities:

```
package ch.zhaw.springboot.entities;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;




@Entity
public class Company {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String Name;
    
    @OneToMany
    private List<Orders> orders;

    public Company() {
    }
    
    


    public Company(long id, String name) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        Name = name;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }


    }




package ch.zhaw.springboot.entities;

import java.sql.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

@Entity
public class Orders {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private long id;

        private Date date;

        
        @ManyToOne
        private Company company;
        @ManyToOne
        private Item item;
    
        
        public Orders() {
        }


        public Orders(long id, Date date) {
            super();
            this.id = id;
            this.date = date;
        }

        
        public Item getItem() {
            return item;
        }
        
        public Company getCompany() {
            return company;
        }

        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }


        public Date getDate() {
            return date;
        }



    
}



package ch.zhaw.springboot.entities;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

import org.hibernate.annotations.NotFound;
import org.hibernate.annotations.NotFoundAction;


@Entity
@org.hibernate.annotations.DiscriminatorOptions(force=true)
public class Item {

    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String Name;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Orders> orders;
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @ManyToOne
    private System system;

    public Item() {
    }
    
    
    public Item(long id, String name) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        Name = name;
    }




    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }


    
}
```

My repository:

```
    package ch.zhaw.springboot.repositories;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import ch.zhaw.springboot.entities.Company;
import ch.zhaw.springboot.entities.Orders;

@Repository
public interface OrdersRepository extends JpaRepository<Orders, Long> 
 {

    @Query(value = "SELECT  b1.company_id, b2.company_id FROM Orders b1, Orders b2\r\n"
            + "WHERE b1.item_id = b2.item_id\r\n"
            + "AND b1.company_id < b2.company_id", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<Company> getCompanyEdgesById(long id);

    
    
}
```

My Controller:

```
package ch.zhaw.springboot.restcontroller;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import ch.zhaw.springboot.entities.Company;
import ch.zhaw.springboot.entities.Item;
import ch.zhaw.springboot.entities.Orders;
import ch.zhaw.springboot.repositories.CompanyRepository;
import ch.zhaw.springboot.repositories.ItemRepository;
import ch.zhaw.springboot.repositories.OrdersRepository;
import ch.zhaw.springboot.repositories.OrdersRepository;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin
public class OrdersRestController {

    @Autowired
    private OrdersRepository repository;
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/Orders", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<Orders>> getOrders() {
        List<Orders> result = this.repository.findAll();
        if (!result.isEmpty()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<List<Orders>>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<List<Orders>>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/Orders/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Orders> getOrdersByID(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
        Optional<Orders> result = this.repository.findById(id);
        if (result.isPresent()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Orders>(result.get(), HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<Orders>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }
    
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "Com/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<Company>> getCompanyEdgesById(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
        List<Company> result = this.repository.getCompanyEdgesById(id);

        if (!result.isEmpty()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<List<Company>>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<List<Company>>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    } 
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: Why don't you alias one or both of the columns in your `SELECT  b1.company_id, b2.company_id` query so they don't both have the same name?